# Rails -- namespaced routing to path helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have the following route rule:

```
get '/reports/stats_by_date', to: 'reports#stats_by_date'
```

And rake routes gives me this:

```
reports_stats_by_date GET    /reports/stats_by_date(.:format)         reports#stats_by_date
```

That looks correct.  So I'm trying to test my controller from within rake with this function:

```
def test_reports_should_load    
  get :reports_stats_by_date, :start_date => '2013-10-01', :end_date => '2013-10-05', :format => :json
  assert_response :success
end
```

Pretty simple.  But when I run rake test, I get the following error:

```
ReportsControllerTest#test_reports_should_load:
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:start_date=>"2013-10-01", :end_date=>"2013-10-05", :format=>:json, :controller=>"reports", :action=>"reports_stats_by_date"}
test/controllers/reports_controller_test.rb:6:in `test_reports_should_load'
```

For some reason, Rails is trying to load up the action :reports_stats_by_date when the route clearly points to reports#stats_by_date.  What did I do wrong here?

Comment: In you test_reports_should_load try get  '/reports/stats_by_date', :start_date => '2013-10-01', :end_date => '2013-10-05', :format => :json. The get generally expects an action name as a symbol rather than a helper method. Let me know if this works

Comment: Nope.  Now I'm getting No route matches ... :action=>"reports/stats_by_date"

Comment: Then this should definitely work get :stats_by_date , :start_date => '2013-10-01', :end_date => '2013-10-05', :format => :json . Now that im giving the action name rather than the path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you only need to reference the action name, not the name of the path. stats_by_date instead of reports_stats_by_date

```
 def test_reports_should_load    
  get :stats_by_date, :start_date => '2013-10-01', :end_date => '2013-10-05', :format => :json
  assert_response :success
end
```

Comment: ok, this is working.  Can someone explain to me how Rails would handle two conflicting routes under different namespaces?  For example, /reports/stats_by_date vs /charts/stats_by_date.